# How to creating a transparent, borderless, full-screen JFrame overlay in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm working on a Java application where I need to implement a transparent, borderless `JFrame` window that overlays other windows while still allowing interaction with underlying windows. Specifically, the overlay window should be fully transparent, borderless, full-screen, and always on top of other windows. However, users should also be able to interact seamlessly with windows behind the overlay.

I've attempted to achieve this using standard Java Swing techniques, but I've encountered limitations in achieving the desired transparency and interaction behavior. Here's what I've tried:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FullScreenGlassPaneExample {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            //frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            //frame.setOpacity(0.8f); 

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            //frame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
            frame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
            frame.setEnabled(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

- Created a `JFrame` with transparency using `setOpacity()` method, but it doesn't support full transparency.
- Tried setting the background color with an alpha value using `setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100))`, but it didn't provide the desired transparency.
- Experimented with `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` to keep the window on top, but it interfered with interaction with underlying windows.

I was expecting the `JFrame` to be fully transparent, borderless, and full-screen, allowing seamless interaction with underlying windows. However, I haven't been able to achieve this with my current approach.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Ultimately using a cross-platform technology at the very front line (windowing) of platform specifics is likely to prove less than adequate. A platform-specifc approach will likely be more satisfactory

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?  Not to secretly intercept user input to other programs, I hope?

Comment: Actually I am working on a project called "Ultra Brightness Manager" in this project, I want to adjust the screen brightness through java program.

Comment: As soon as you make the frame non-transparent, the mouse events will be intercepted by the frame and not passed to the underlying component. So, I don't think this will solve your problem.